# Confusing Operator Precedence 2 / 5 * 3 in PHP

Tags: php, operator-precedence

As PHP's Manual shows, the following operators have the same priority (left associativity):

`* / %`

So, It means:

`echo 2 / 5 * 3`

must display 7.5! because the multiplication will perform first, `5 * 3 = 15` then the quotient will divided by 2.

But when I run that code, PHP code outputs 1.2!

Could anyone please to understand what's going on?

Comment: [Check This](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=2+%2F+5+*+3&oq=2+%2F+5+*+3&aqs=chrome..69i57.1743j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) Output is perfect

Comment: **same priority** , which means, first comes first goes...

Comment: I'd expect math rules to be followed, which they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **order to execute arithmetic operations**. which call short [**`PEMDAS`**](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm)

1. `()` - brackets
2. `/` - deviation
3. `*` - multiplication
4. `+` - add
5. `-` - min

This will(`2 / 5 * 3`) **execute** in above **order**

---

So **what happen on here** `2 / 5 * 3`

1. `2/5` = **0.4**
2. `0.4*3` = **1.2**

---

**To fulfill your requirement**

1. `5 * 3` = **15**
2. `15 / 2` = **7.5**

So you have to do `(5 * 3) / 2` or `2 / (5 * 3)`

---

[PHPFiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1x0q-6uem)

Comment: PEMDAS or (Please Excuse My Aunt Dear Sally) means:
* Parentheses.
* Exponent.
* Multiplication.
* Division.
* Addition.
* Subtraction.

and in my example above, the result must be: 7.5, because the multiplication must performed first. Isn't right?

Comment: i mention **orders list.** it will flow like that

Comment: @Ahmad what happen. Any pogress??

Answer (score 3):

Same priority means that everything will happen from left to right.

Meaning that it won't multiply first. The order in which `* / %` was written in the manual does not matter.

- 2 / 5 = 0.4
- 0.4 * 3 = 1.2

Also, by your logic, you should be getting 1.(3) but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's left to right
2/5=0.4
0.4*3=1.2

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

the operator * / and % has the same precedence. * has the same precedence as /.